# класс матрицы надо ввести значения

Tags: c++

есть класс матрица и необходимо ввести значения элементов, при такой реализации у меня ничего не работает

```
 class SqrMatrix
        {
        private:
            double **matrix;
            double **result;
            int size;
        public:
            SqrMatrix(int sizeofmymatrix)
            {
                size = sizeofmymatrix;
                double **matrix = new double*[size];
                double **result = new double*[size];
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeofmymatrix; i++)
                {
                    matrix[i] = new double[sizeofmymatrix];
                    result[i] = new double[sizeofmymatrix];
                }
            }
            void SqrMatrix::fillmatrix()
            {
                cout << "введите элементы матрицы" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                    {
                        cin >> matrix[i][j];
                    }
                }
                cout << "матрица заполнена!" << endl;
            }
            ~SqrMatrix()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    delete[](matrix[i]);
                    delete[](result[i]);
                }
                delete[](matrix);
                delete[](result);
            }
        };
void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "RUSSIAN");
    SqrMatrix mat(4);
    mat.fillmatrix();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собирать и анализировать код я даже не пытался, потому как и без этого видно первый ляп:

```
SqrMatrix(int sizeofmymatrix)
{
    size = sizeofmymatrix;
    double **matrix = new double*[size];
    double **result = new double*[size];
```

Здесь вы выделяете память под **локальные** переменные `matrix` и `result` (которая, само собой, потом теряется, но речь даже не про это). А потом пытаетесь работать с членами класса `SqrMatrix::matrix` и `SqrMatrix::result`, которые к вышеуказанным переменным никакого отношения не имеют, и нигде не проинициализированы.

P.S. Пользуйтесь анализаторами кода и будет вам счастье. [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/), например, моментально выдаёт:

> Member 'matrix' was not initialized in this constructor main.cpp (Code
>   Analysis Problem) Member 'result' was not initialized in this
>   constructor main.cpp (Code Analysis Problem)

Comment: и как мне быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: Очевидно, инициализировать не локальны переменные, а переменные класса. Ну и парочку других косяков исправить, типа `void main` + `void SqrMatrix::fillmatrix()`. И прикрутить-таки к IDE cppcheck :) А если она это не позволяет - сменить её.

Comment: в общем разобрался я с данной проблемой, оказалось что в конструкторе я неправильно делаю динамический массив. а в остальном косяков нету. кстати cppcheck крутиться к vs13?

Comment: Там на главной странице ссылка на плагин для VS. Как работает не знаю, ибо винды вижу редко и только в виртуалке :)

Comment: "а в остальном косяков нету" этот код глобальный косяк. Лучшее что можно сделать с ним - стереть и забыть. Зачем писать на C++ (или делать вид) и вместо std::vector<double> делать такую чудовищную хрень с  new double[size]/delete[]?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>

class SqrMatrix
{
  std::vector<double> matrix;
public:
  SqrMatrix( int sz ) : matrix( sz * sz ) {}

  void fillmatrix()
  {
    std::cout << "введите элементы матрицы" << std::endl;
    for( auto i = matrix.begin(), e = matrix.end(); i != e; ++i )
      std::cin >> *i;

    std::cout << "матрица заполнена!" << std::endl;
   }
};

void main()
{
 setlocale(0, "RUSSIAN");
 SqrMatrix mat(4);
 mat.fillmatrix();
}
```

P.S. для C++ старше 11го auto заменить на std::vector::iterator